# Sending back data from an Angular directive using a template variable

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have a bunch of directives,

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[someDirective1]"
})
export class SomeDirective1 {}


@Directive({
  selector: "[someDirective2]"
})
export class SomeDirective2 {
    @Input() blah: String
    ...
}
```

Let's say I use it as follow:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'blah-component'
  template: `
    <div someDirective1>
      <div someDirective2>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class BlahComponent {
    
    
}
```

Now I want to pass a parameter from `someDirective1` to `someDirective2`

The usual way would be to declare an `@Output` on `someDirective1`, capture that value in `BlahComponent` which would then be passed in as an `@Input` again

```
@Component({
  selector: 'blah-component'
  template: `
    <div someDirective1 (somethingChanged)="changeSomething($event)">
        <div someDirective2 [blah]="somethingThatChanged">
        </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class BlahComponent {
   
   somethingThatChanged: string

   function changeSomething(value) {
     ....
     somethingThatChanged = ...
   } 
    
}
```

Is there a way to do it without the Output-Function-TempVariable-Input boiler-plate?
Something like this (this is not valid syntax, looking for something that will work conceptually like this):

```
@Component({
 selector: 'blah-component'
 template: `
    <div someDirective1={ let someContext }>
        <div someDirective2 [blah]="someContext.someValue">
        </div>
    </div>
 `
})
export class BlahComponent {
    
    
}
```

Question is related to Angular 9, 10, 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use exportAs property on the Directive decorator,By setting this property we can expose directive instance to template, Finally using template variable we can access directive instance anywhere on template.

**directive1.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[someDirective1]",
  exportAs: 'someDirective1'
})
export class SomeDirective1 {}
```

**directive2.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[someDirective2]",
  exportAs: 'someDirective2'
})
export class SomeDirective2 {
    @Input() blah: String
    ...
}
```

Inside template define template variable to access directive instance

```
@Component({
 selector: 'blah-component'
 template: `
    <div someDirective1 #d1="someDirective1">
        <div someDirective2 [blah]="d1.someValue">
        </div>
    </div>
 `
})
export class BlahComponent {}
```